# Finding repeated characters in arguments to function with variable-length argument list

Tags: c, function, variadic

The function has to read from the characters provided in the argument list, then stop as soon as it finds two the same, or when it reaches a null byte argument. I believe I've got that part coded. But I can't understand how to account for the first character 'a'; it skips that character, and I can't figure out how to compare the two.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

char fancyMostFrequentChar(char c, ...);

int main(void)
{
    char c = fancyMostFrequentChar('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'b', 'a', '\0');

    if (c == 'd')
        printf("Hooray!\n");
    else
        printf("fail whale :(\n");

    return 0;
}

char fancyMostFrequentChar(char c, ... )
{
    int ci;
    int i;
    int alpha[26] = {0};
    int max = 0;
    int max_i = 0;
    int total = c;

    printf("%d\n\n", c);

    va_list letters;

    va_start(letters, c);

    while((i = va_arg(letters, int))!= 0)
    {
        ci = i - 97;
        printf("%d\n", ci);
    }

    alpha[ci] = c;

    printf("%d", alpha[ci]);

    va_end(letters);

    return total;
}
```

Comment: If `alpha[ci]` is not zero, you've found a duplicate; return it (remembering `va_end`). Otherwise, set it to 1.

Comment: You have to process the first argument specially. You don't need to check whether it's a duplicate; it isn't. But you do need to set the right entry in `alpha` to 1.

Comment: Any idea how i would put that in code?

Comment: [Basic idea](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/a9fccc41-efdb-4736-9ae1-1a571b929591/view-source)

Comment: BLUEPIXY hey man u helped me on the last one and i greatly appreciate that. Im just confused on how i do the same thing but with characters now and then accounting for the first character that it skips and also making sure nothing = 0;

Comment: I didn't carefully read the code but, from the description, the function has a very big design flaw: if the list of input arguments do not contain duplicates and it also doesn't contain a null character, the function's behaviour is undefined. It keeps reading from the list of arguments beyond its end.

Comment: Trust me my intro to c class was damn near pointless. We barely even spoke of funtions and now i have to be 100% fluent in them so i have no idea whats going on.

Answer (score 1):

The main text says 'stop as soon as it finds two the same'; the code says 'fancyMostFrequentChar' which means you have to count all characters and report the most frequent one.  Different operations.

#### First duplicate

For the first, if `alpha[ci]` is not zero, you've found a duplicate; return it (remembering va_end). Otherwise, set `alpha[c1]` to 1.  For the second, you have to process all arguments and then find the most frequent.  You have to process the first argument specially. You don't need to check whether it's a duplicate; it isn't. But you do need to set the right entry in `alpha` to 1.  Note that this code doesn't barf if you pass a non-letter, and it treats upper and lower case letters as the same.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

char first_duplicate(char c, ...);

int main(void)
{
    char c = first_duplicate('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'b', 'a', '\0');

    if (c == 'd')
        printf("Hooray!\n");
    else
        printf("fail whale :(\n");

    return 0;
}

static inline int map_char(unsigned char u)
{
    if (isalpha(u))
        return tolower(u) - 'a';
    return 26;
}

char first_duplicate(char c, ...)
{
    int i;
    int alpha[26] = {0};
    va_list letters;
    va_start(letters, c);

    alpha[map_char(c)] = 1;

    while ((i = va_arg(letters, int)) != 0)
    {
        int n = map_char(i);
        if (n != 26 && alpha[n] != 0)
        {
            va_end(letters);
            return n + 'a';
        }
        alpha[n]++;
    }
    va_end(letters);
    return c;   // No duplicates spotted - return first letter
}
```

#### Most frequent letter

For the most frequent letter, you have to process the entire argument list, and then find which entry has the most occurrences.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

char fancyMostFrequentChar(char c, ...);

int main(void)
{
    char c = fancyMostFrequentChar('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'b', 'a', '\0');

    if (c == 'a')
        printf("Hooray!\n");
    else
        printf("fail whale :(\n");

    return 0;
}

static inline int map_char(unsigned char u)
{
    if (isalpha(u))
        return tolower(u) - 'a';
    return 26;
}

char fancyMostFrequentChar(char c, ...)
{
    int i;
    int alpha[26] = {0};
    va_list letters;
    va_start(letters, c);

    alpha[map_char(c)] = 1;

    while ((i = va_arg(letters, int)) != 0)
    {
        int n = map_char(i);
        if (n != 26)
            alpha[n]++;
    }
    va_end(letters);

    int maxval = alpha[0];
    int maxpos = 0;
    for (i = 1; i < 26; i++)
    {
        if (alpha[i] > maxval)
        {
            maxval = alpha[i];
            maxpos = i;
        }
    }
    return maxpos + 'a';
}
```

Both compile cleanly and produce `Hooray!` when run.

Note that it would be more sensible, and plausible, to pass a single character string to the function, which would not need to use `<stdarg.h>` at all.  It could also produce different answers based on user input, etc.  The code using variable arguments is more or less stuck using a fixed length of argument list (though you could have different variables providing the values (`first_duplicate(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, '\0');`) if you wanted to).